# Invalid input for type time: 'start_time' , how to write ths query properly in postgresql?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, time, timestamp

I want to select a program which has a session in a specific time and day but I can't cast type time, i got this error: invalid input syntax for type time: 'start_time';
Here is the query I wrote:

```
SELECT *
      FROM programs
      WHERE (
        SELECT *
        FROM unnest(sessions) AS session
        WHERE session->>'day' = :day
        AND :currentDate::time BETWEEN (to_timestamp(session->>'start_time', 'HH24:MI:SS')::time - (entry_time_range || ' minutes')::interval)::time
        AND (session->>'start_time'::time + (entry_time_range || ' minutes')::interval)::time
      )              
      AND( filter IS NULL
          OR filter LIKE :schedule
        )
      AND :currentDate BETWEEN startline AND deadline       
      AND facility_id = :facility_id;
```

How can I solve this? Why does it not work ?
the start_time in database is like "13:00:33". it is inside of a json object which belongs to a sessions array. In my query I unnest the sessions array in order to be able to access each json object.
I tried both with start_time::time and to_timestamp method. Both give me the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the issue, you're casting a piece of text to time:

> session->>'start_time'::time

'start_time' is now casted to time, at least that's what this piece of code is trying to do.

Using a clean CAST avoids this issue:

> CAST(session->>'start_time' AS time)

Another option is some extra ( and ):

> (session->>'start_time')::time

But harder to read and thus error prone